# Reading from file stops working

Tags: c++

So i have this problem in c++.

I open a file and read it char by char and print it on screen.

It works fine until I add this to the program.

```
gr=0;
```

The complete program:

```
int main()
{
    int gr;
    char *ch;
    gr=0;//this causes the problem

    FILE *fp;
    fp=fopen("as.txt","r");
    do
    {
        *ch=fgetc(fp);
        cout<<*ch<<endl;
    }
    while (*ch!=EOF);
}
```

Comment: How does it "stop working"? Do you have debugger? That extra assignment shouldn't cause any problems.

Comment: It just says pojname.exe has stopped working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
char *ch;
*ch=fgetc(fp);
```

You created a pointer, but you never actually made it point to anything.

That it appeared to work without the `gr=0` assignment is pure chance, likely a result of various factors contributing to values in memory. When you dereference invalid pointers, sometimes you get a segmentation fault and othertimes you just silently overwrite some memory that's not yours, causing further bugs down the line.

I have no idea what you need a pointer for here, anyway. Surely simply declare a `char ch` and use that.

Comment: Oh yes,I don't know why I used pointers I guess I got confused.That solved the problem.Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seg faults on me. You might try something like the code listed below.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    char c;
    fp=fopen("str.cpp","r");
    if(fp != NULL) {
        do {
            c=fgetc(fp);
            std::cout << c << std::endl;
        } while (c!=EOF);
    }
}
```

Comment: Turns out the problem was using pointer on character ch.Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the `char` pointer.You never actually allocate memory for it it's just some random pointer thus giving you undefined behavior.This is why it worked without the `gr` on your machine but it's just random and it won't work in most cases.
What you want to do is allocate memory for it like that :

```
int main()
{
    int gr;
    char *ch=new char;
    gr=0;//this has nothing to do with the problem

    FILE *fp;
    fp=fopen("as.txt","r");
    do
    {
        *ch=fgetc(fp);
        cout<<*ch<<endl;
    }
    while (*ch!=EOF);
    delete ch; //For each new there must be a delete
    return 0;
}
```